# How to use '||' in if-else statement in iphone appllication?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
if((([txtFldO1.text length] == 0 ) || ([txtFldO2.text length] == 0 ) || 
([txtFldO3.text length] == 0 ) || ([txtFldO4.text length] == 0 ) || 
([txtFldO5.text length] == 0 )) && (([txtFldR1.text length]== 0) || 
([txtFldR2.text length]== 0) || ([txtFldR3.text length]== 0) || ([txtFldR4.text length]== 0) || ([txtFldR5.text length]== 0)))
    {
             //alert
             //return
         }
```

This statement does not work. It does access all of the propeties. Could anyone tell me why?
I need to access one txtFldO and one txtFldR.

Comment: Is there a [code] tag!!!

Comment: @Nilesh: How does it not work? What error messages do you get? @Paska: No there isn't.

Comment: @WTP correct :), but I suggest to indent code...

Comment: This functionality would be cleaner with more descriptive variable names, and a loop instead of repeated syntax in a long if clause.  For example, something like: BOOL aFieldIsEmpty = NO; for (int i = 0; i < numFields; ++i) if ([textField[i] length] == 0) aFieldIsEmpty = YES; /* then outside the for loop */ if (aFieldIsEmpty) { /* react to a field being empty */ }  Hard to code in comments here!

Answer (score 0):

To access properties, try **SELF**

`self.txtFld00.text.length`

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this.

```
if([txtFldO1.text length] == 0 || [txtFldO2.text length] == 0 || [txtFldO3.text length] == 0 || [txtFldO4.text length] == 0){

// Code here 

}
```

You don't need to put parentheses before condition. Just put one parentheses like above example.

Hope this help.